# Why isn't the ε-δ definition $\mid f(x) - L\mid < ε \Rightarrow 0 < \mid x - a\mid < δ$? Why can't you reverse δ,ε in the implication?

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

Here's the definition of a limit that I was taught: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ means:
$\forall \varepsilon  > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that
$0 < \mid x - a\mid < \delta \to \mid f(x) - L\mid <\varepsilon $

1. In the following picture, why doesn't the limit exist at $a_1$ based on the definition of a limit?

[image]

Simply because $f(x)$ is not defined on the given interval?

2. Can the definition be written as:
   $\mid f(x) - L\mid < \varepsilon \Rightarrow 0 < \mid x - a\mid < \delta$?

Basically, why is the equality one way and not two ways (iff)? If you want to specify how close you want $f(x)$ to be to $L$, then find out how close $x$ needs to be to $c$ in order to guarantee it, why does the delta part imply the epsilon part? This seems a little un-intuitive.

Comment: We usually assume that $a$ is a cluster point of the domain of $f$ to talk about a limit at $a$.

Comment: We have not talked about cluster points, but I was simply wondering how the definition can be used to show some function (like the one above) that is discontinuous does not have a limit at certain points, like at $a_1$.

Comment: Is your function $f$ not defined in a neighborhood of $a_1$?

Comment: We don’t write it both ways for (at least) two reasons. The first is that we simply do not really care about the other direction; the important thing is the *control* of always being able to fix a $\delta$ which squeezes $f$ within $\epsilon$. The second is that $f$ can be close to $L$ in all sorts of places; consider a periodic function like sine. The limit as $x$ goes to zero is zero, but sine takes on the value of zero at infinitely many other places, so the reverse implication fails. It is then only really in the case of monotone functions that we will get the other direction to work

Comment: If $f$ is not defined near $L$, as is clear from your graph, there exist no delta such that the condition is satisfied, as the expression $|f(x)-L|$ has no meaning for $x$ near $a$.

Comment: @FShrike So, to prove it is false, I would show that ∣f(x)−L∣<ε⇒∣x−a∣$\geq$δ, and since it implies both ∣x−0∣ which is less than some δ and approaches 0, and ∣x−π∣ approaches 0 but is larger than δ, the conditional fails? Am I over complicating things? Is there a more simple way of seeing why the reverse implication fails?

Comment: That’s right. For $x$ close to $\pi$, $|f(x)|\lt\epsilon$ but $|x|\gt\delta$ once delta is chosen small enough

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2806162) answers your 2nd question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions here:

1. Why doesn't the limit exist in your graph?
2. Why is a limit defined using implication and not equivalence.

**Question 1**

To say $\lim_{x\to a} =L$ we need $|x-a|\leq \delta \implies |f(x) -L|\leq \epsilon$  **for all** $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Let's define $x_l, x_r$ as the closest values of $x$ to $a$ where $f(x)$ is defined, when approaching from the left and right, respectively.

If we want to say $L=f(x_l)$ then for any $\epsilon > 0$ we need to find a $\delta >0$ so that $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ if $0<|x-a|<\delta$. However, we can see that if $\delta < |a-x_l|$ then $f(x)$ is not defined for any $x \in |x-a|<\delta$. If $\delta>|x_l-a|$ then $f(x)$ is not defined for any $x\in (x_l,a)$ so we fail to satisfy the definition (there is no "get out of logic free" card for undefined points ;-)

**Question 2**

If we changed the definition to be

$$\lim_{x\to a} =L \text{ when }$$
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0\;\exists \delta > 0: 0<|x-a|\leq \delta \iff |f(x)- L| \leq \epsilon$$

Then any function that is not strictly monotonic would fail to have a limit, since $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$ could happen at two disjoint intervals of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

**The limit in your picture doesn't exist at $a_1$ by the definition**

So the definition of limit is technically two parts. The definition you cited is only the second part. The first part requires that there is an open interval $I$ containing $a$ such that $I\setminus \{a\} \subseteq \operatorname{dom} (f)$ which in your picture will not be satisfied since $(a_1-\delta, a_1+\delta) \cap \operatorname{dom} (f)=\emptyset$ where $\delta:=\operatorname{dist}(a_1, \operatorname{dom} (f))$. So the limit at $a_1$ doesn't exist in your figure because the first part of the definition is not satisfied.

Note: Sometimes people bake in the first part of the definition such as how [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Limit_of_Real_Function#Definition) did by stipulating the domain of $f$ to be $(a,b) \setminus \{c\}$.

**Example of why the converse is not a part of the definition**

Consider the constant function $f(x)=1$ on $\mathbb R$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Since $f$ is constant, we trivially have
$|f(x)-1|<\varepsilon$ BUT notice there is no $\delta \in (0,\infty)$ that guarantees $0<|x-a|<\delta$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (consider $x=\delta+|a|$).
Moreover, when the function $f$ is continuous at $a$ there is no delta that somehow implies $x \neq a$ since $x=a$ will always satisfy $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$.